# How to highlight a button without pressing it on Android

Tags: android, button

How can I highlight a button for just a certain amount of time (e.g., 1 or 2 seconds) without actually pressing it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to set focus for a certain period of time....

here's how you can do it:

```
    button01.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    button01.requestFocus();
```

In some htc handsets this highlights the button as green in some LG phones Yellow. The focus color is basically the device property.

After this you can apply your logic to set focus to some other object after appropriate time, so button01 will lose focus and be its normal self again.

```
    someOtherView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
    someOtherView.RequestFocus();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! My problem now is: "set the focus to some other object after appropriate time"!
I am creating a sort of karaoke app. Each word is a button and I want to highlight them in synch while they are played, so I use a loop:

for (int i = 1;i<fl.getChildCount();++i) {                   Button btn = (Button) fl.getChildAt(i);          btn.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);            btn.requestFocus();           mTts.speak((String) btn.getText(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, myHashAlarm);
}

==> ONLY THE LAST BUTTON IS HIGHLIGHTED! Any ideas???

Comment: I got the problem.... the for loop actually sets focus in all the buttons but removes focus almost instantly...when it goes to the last button focus stays there as the loop is over.... I would recomment using android's CountDownTimer or AlarmManager (not sure about alarm manager though) to give a certain delay before moving the focus to the next child Button.... Another approach can be using handlers..... you can send message.sendEmptyMessage(3) after textToSpeech finishes and then you can set focus to other button or views...

Comment: sendEmptyMessage(3) is just an example.... you can access 3 inside handler as (msg.what==3)

Comment: I tried to use a CountDownTimer but it highlights all the buttons very quickly and then the highlight stays on the last button again...
I will try the second solution with handlers. I have never used them, I am not sure I really understood how they worked. I had to call message.sendEmptyMessage(n)  after  the TTS and then i set the focus of my button in the handler?

Comment: you can increase the time delay in countdowntimers as well

Comment: Thanks, it works (see the code bellow). The highlight stays for the last button! How can i delete it? I tried "button.clearFocus();" but it did not work! Cheers!

Comment: can you please try button.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); and then clear focus.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to make it works. If someone is interested in creating a sort of karaoke, here is my code:

```
public void playKaraoke(final FlowLayout fl) {
        //KARAOKE
        mTts.setLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);
            // Do something long
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 1;i<fl.getChildCount();++i) {
                        final Button btn = (Button) fl.getChildAt(i);
                         btn.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(800);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //progress.setProgress(value);
                                 btn.requestFocus();
                                 mTts.speak((String) btn.getText(),
                                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,  // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
                                            null);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();

    }
```